# Active MQ Artemis, most of the addresses and queue disappeared after HA failover

Tags: high-availability, activemq-artemis

Ubuntu 18.04
Artemis 2.14

I've been experimenting with HA. Usually I can shut down the primary, and the secondary comes alive, with all the addresses and queues. But today I shut the primary down and the secondary came to life but with only a few of the addresses and queues. Some addresses appeared with no queues, some with only one, but most were totally missing.

I started the primary broker again, and HA switched back, but still without all the objects. They're all setup the same, for the most part.

I created the objects (addresses and queues) through the console, then used the data tools to export them from the journal and an import them into this instance -- which I'm preparing to run as the production instance.

What would cause the objects to disappear? Should I instead define them in the broker.xml file?

Comment: Are you using shared-store or replication? Are you creating the queues as durable? Why are you creating the resources via the console instead of just defining them in the XML? Finally, do you have clear steps to reliably reproduce the issue?

Comment: I was trying to reproduce it, but haven't been able to. I'm using replication, no shared-store, and creating durable queues. Is it better then to define the objects in the broker.xml?

Comment: "Better" is relative to your use-case. Since you haven't described your use-case (i.e. *why* you're creating the resources via the console) I can't really comment on which is better. I will say that it does seem a bit odd to create resources via the console, stop the broker, export them, and then import them into another instance when you could just configure what you need in the XML and use that in both places.

Comment: Also, if you're using a single HA pair with replication your in danger of [split brain](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/network-isolation.html). I recommend you use 3 live/backup pairs to establish a proper quorum. This will help mitigate against split brain. Another alternative would be to use shared-store instead of replication. The file locks in that configuration prevent split brain.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. That advice sounds pretty good.

Comment: Let me know if you come up with a way to reproduce this, and I'll take the reproducer and investigate. For what it's worth there are a number of fail-over & fail-back tests in the test-suite and everything is working as expected.

Comment: OK. Would 3 live/backup pairs look like this? server1/server2, server2/server3, server3/server4

Comment: Three pairs can be configured in a number of different ways. I recommend you create a new question about this if you need additional info.